# Remove CALL_LOG and SMS permission in ejected React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, expo, create-react-app

I tried to remove the CALL_LOG and SMS permission within my React Native app to compliant with Google new policy. However, after multiple tried, I can't seem to get the alert message on Google Dev Console go away. It seem my APK still have not remove these permission. In my Android Manifest, I added

```
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SMS" />
```

Also I tried to search all of my project and see that the CALL_LOG and SMS permission is nowhere to be found. If anyone had successful remove these permission with their ejected RN app can help me, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expo then you should tell the application which permissions it should be granted in the app.json file. If you do not specify which permissions it should be granted it will try to grant itself all of the permissions such as READ_SMS.

The app.json permissions section could look something like this:

```
"android": {
  "permissions": [
    "RECORD_AUDIO"
  ]
}
```

For a list of all of the permissions and more detailed information please see these links:
[Expo permissions documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions), [Expo permissions list](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration.html#android).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you were doing the same error as me but you need to **replace** the existing entry

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS" />
```

with

```xml
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SMS" />
```

on the manifest.xml instead of adding it.

Otherwise it will just add that permission anyway.